# gradle error : ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add Firebase to my chat app in android studio, but all provided `build.gradle` plugins are not syncing.

I have tried some code below:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

and then comes

> ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Where are you adding the line `implementation ...` ??

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when adding Firebase into my Ionic app. Turns out I was putting the line `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` under the `dependencies` found within `buildscript` when this line should have been placed within the `dependencies` at the app-level (see below).

Put `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` here:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

**not** here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}
```

If it helps, I found the app-level dependencies section near the bottom of my project-level `build.gradle` file.

Good luck!

Comment: What version of gradle are you using, apparently mine isn't working on gradle 2.1.2

UPDATE: it requires a minimum of 3.4 to use the "implementation" keyword, otherwise you should use "compile" which is deprecated